# How to see if a div's bottom is 100 px from bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using sticky class to stick a div. The problem is that it sticks correctly from top but at the bottom, it overlaps the footer.

[image]

This is my HTML

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active " id="menu1">
    <div class="col-sm-12"><div class="clear">&nbsp;</div></div>

    <!-- LEFT NAV START -->
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="sticky-anchor2">
    <div class="sticky2">
    <span style="color:red"><strong>Menu Group</strong></span>
    <ul aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $key => $value) { ?>
        <li role="presentation">
        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="<?php echo $nav_url; ?>#cat_<?php echo str_replace(' ', '_', trim($key)); ?>" class="anchorLink" style="color:#FFF !important;">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block setlbl" type="button"><?php echo $key; ?></button></a>
        </li>

        <?php } ?>
        </ul>
</div>
```

This is my jquery code.

```
var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
var div_top2 = $('#sticky-anchor2').offset().top - 100;
if (window_top > div_top2) {
    $('.sticky2').addClass('sticky stick');
} else {
    $('.sticky2').removeClass('sticky stick');
}
```

What I want is that if the div is, let's say **150 px** from bottom, it should **remove** the stick class. What should I do?

Comment: can you add your HTML code also??

Comment: Did that @JhonCarpenter

Comment: @ Ali Zia, show in fiddle?

Comment: I don't know how to use fiddle :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

It' working, try my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v3kq1ddd/
or run the snippet in full screen and resize the window and you will see the border change from red to blue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var eHeight = $(".sticky2").height();
        var eTop = $(".sticky2").offset().top;
        var tot = eHeight + eTop;
        var heightDifference = $(window).height() - tot;

        $('.height').text(heightDifference);

        if(heightDifference < 150) {
            $('.sticky2').addClass('blue');
        } else {
            $('.sticky2').removeClass('blue');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.sticky2 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.blue {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<lable>Space to buttom</lable>
<div class="height"></div>
<div class="sticky2">detta är en div</div>
```

Comment: I added a document ready function. Try my fiddle or the snippet @AliZia

Answer (score 0):

> I am taking document height and window height, if have some particular
>   Div please take the height of that.
>
> You have to calculate scroll Amount at each and every scroll, so
>   'Scroll' event will be used which will fire at every scroll.  Other
>   thing to remember if 'sticky stick', is not two different class use
>   hyphen between them.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
           var scrollamount=$(window).scrollTop();
            var totalheight=($(document).height() - ($(window).height()));

             if(scrollamount > totalheight-100)
                {
                  $('.sticky2').addClass('sticky_stick');
                 }
             else
              $('.sticky2').removeClass('sticky_stick');



 });
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2jo69opo/